# Add plugin to phonegap project using config.xml

Tags: cordova, plugins

I would like to add plugins to my phonegap project in "automatic" way. For example when I get project from version control system, I don't want to add all plugins manually (with CLI or plugman) again. I found that it's possible to use config.xml for this purpose but it does not work or I do it wrong. I tried to add following:

```
<gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner" version="2.0.1" />
```

and also I tried:

```
<feature name="barcodescanner">
  <param name="id" value="com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner" />
  <param name="version" value="2.0.1" />
</feature>
```

But it doesn't work. I have installed phonegap 4.2.0-0.23.0 and I use phonegap 3.5.0 in config.xml

Comment: that only works if you use phonegap build

Answer (score 0):

Well, using `feature` is all right but I thought that `phonegap build` would be enough for adding plugins to project. But in fact it's necessary to call:

```
phonegap restore plugins --experimental
```